# функция , принимающая на вход количество появлений данного слова и общее количество слов, а возвращать совместную информацию для данного слова

Tags: python

```
def word_self_information(word_count: int, total_count: int) -> float:
    return None

word2information = {}
for word, word_count in word2count.items():
    word2information[word] = word_self_information(word_count, total_count)
```

Comment: зачем вы удалили прошлый вопрос

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Вообще не понятно, в чём состоит вопрос. Ну, функция, ну, код. И?? От нас-то что требуется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def word_self_information(word_count: int, total_count: int) -> float:
    return 100 / total_count * word_count
```

Comment: спасибо большое , Danis, вопрос удалила случайно...

Comment: @kate1999 если мой ответ вам помог то примите его

Comment: в каком разделе можно принять?

Comment: @kate1999 слева от моего ответа есть галочка нажмите на неё

Comment: спасибо еще раз